# How can I print any website content? (Using something like my code)

Tags: python

I want to open the website and get its content, store it in a variable and print it

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = any_website

content = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

print(content)
```

The expected result is that I get what is written in the page

Comment: You might be interested in the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) package

Answer (score 2):

In `python`, there are several libraries you may be interested in. An example of printing contents to get you started below:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multinational_corporations"
page = requests.get(url)
page_html = (page.content)
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
print (page_soup)
```

with `urlopen`, you may try as below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multinational_corporations"
r = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
print type(soup)
print (soup.prettify()[0:1000])
```

Comment: nice, the second I tried the second option and it printed the Source Code, but thats not a problem. thanks.

Comment: try `soup.get_text()` and you will get text as well, you can explore this library for further requirments